# Difference between Document and document

Tags: javascript, html, domdocument

I had thought `Document` and `document` was always the same.

But the console shows, `Document` is a `function` in chrome,

while `document` is a `object`. Why?

Why is the former used?

I've searched SO, but I didn't get the answer and I [googled](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=difference+between+Document+and+document&rlz=1C1DFOC_enIN576IN576&oq=difference+between+Document+and+document&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.12700j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), but still I didn't get my answer.

And how to use the `Document` since it is a function?

Answer (score 0):

`Document` is the constructor for an HTML document in Chrome.

`document` is the instance of `Document` for the current window.